# Counting DATEDIFF from MAX records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I am trying to pull together the last login time from users that are being stored in a table daily.

The query below pulls that information for each user:

```
SELECT 
    [Login_name],
    MAX([last_login_time]) as Last_login_date,
    [server_instance]
FROM 
    [dbo].[User_Login_Audit]
WHERE 
    Login_name NOT IN ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
GROUP BY 
    Login_name, server_instance
```

The results are as follows:

```
User_name | 2016-07-28  | Server/Instance
```

What I want is to be able to add the number of days between `GETDATE()` that the max record date and add it as the last column..

I have tried using the following code, but it returns a value for each day that has been recorded for that user. Any help would be appreciated as I am sure I'm missing something obvious.

```
SELECT 
    [Login_name],
    MAX([last_login_time]) AS Last_login_date,
    [server_instance],
    DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), last_login_time) AS Days
FROM 
    [dbo].[User_Login_Audit]
WHERE
    Login_name NOT IN ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
GROUP BY 
    Login_name, server_instance, last_login_time
```

Comment: you need to remove _last_login_time_ from Group by section

Comment: As soon as I do that I get the error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
Column 'dbo.User_Login_Audit.last_login_time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [Login_name],
    max([last_login_time]) Last_login_date,
  [server_instance],
  DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), max([last_login_time])) Days
FROM [dbo].[User_Login_Audit]
where  Login_name not in ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
Group by Login_name, server_instance
```

Comment: That one did it.  Much appreciated.

Comment: yeah, as soon as you added `last_login_time` to group by clause, you're guaranteed to get one row in output for each value of `last_login_time`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ;with cte
 as
( SELECT
 [Login_name]
 ,max([last_login_time]) as Last_login_date
 ,[server_instance],
 FROM [dbo].[User_Login_Audit]
  where  Login_name not in ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
Group by Login_name,server_instance
 )
select *,
 DATEDIFF(day,getdate(),Last_login_date)
from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT 
    u1.[Login_name],
    u1.[server_instance],
    COALESCE(MAX(u2.[last_login_time]),'No previous') AS Last_login_date,
    COALESCE(DATEDIFF(day, getdate(), MAX(u2.last_login_time)), 'No previous') AS Days
FROM 
    [dbo].[User_Login_Audit] ua1
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[User_Login_Audit] ua2 ON ua1.[Login_name] = ua2.[Login_name] and 
                                                ua1.[server_instance] = ua2.[server_instance] and 
                                                u1.[last_login_time] > u2 .[last_login_time]
WHERE
    u1.Login_name NOT IN ('NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'sa','')
GROUP BY 
    u1.Login_name, u1.server_instance
```